# Mat: Namespace Poppler not available

Tags: software-installation, file-metadata

I've installed [MAT: Metadata Anonymisation Toolkit](https://mat.boum.org/). When I tried to run mat, I got following error:

```
user@user ~ $ mat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mat", line 10, in <module>
    from libmat import mat
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libmat/mat.py", line 22, in <module>
    import strippers  # this is loaded here because we need LOGGING_LEVEL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libmat/strippers.py", line 9, in <module>
    import office
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libmat/office.py", line 15, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Poppler', '0.18')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 102, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Poppler not available
```

I don't know how to fix this. Help.

Information about my system:

```
user@user ~ $ uname -a
Linux user 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 17:48:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: @dsstorefile with `sudo apt-get install mate`

Answer (score 4):

You need to install `gir1.2-poppler-0.18`. It doesn't install with `mat`, but `mat` needs it to run.

Ubuntu installation package can be found [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/gir1.2-poppler-0.18_0.86.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html).

Comment: This solved my problem with the python program pympress ! under Ubuntu 2022.4